# String to function conversion with included arguments in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I tried stringing together the following input data in order to send it to SQLAlchemy as a date field:

```
dob_list = raw_input("Enter date of birth. Format: YYYY M D: ").split(' ')
program_data.date_of_birth_transformed = 'date(' + dob_list[0] + ', ' + dob_list[1] + ', ' + dob_list[2] + ')'
```

Issue is that it arrives as a string. I need to send it as a function with arguments, quotes removed.

I appreciate any advice, thank you.

Comment: Any reason you can't just create a `datetime.date` object from `dob_list`? (or even better - the original input string). Then everything else just follows...

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks.